# marker id changes when set tag instance

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I am working with google maps and markers to display some information about location where picture was taking and other info about that.

So basicly i have a activity where i have a list of photos that are related to a specific plant and inside that activity i have a option to see it on map. When i press on that option all of the photos(that has a location) are displayed as gree markers on the map, the currentPhoto clicked is displayed as a yellow marker.

So when i click on the "see on map" i pass the array of all my photos, the selected photo id, and the current location of the user.

**Like this:**

```
 public void showMap(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("currentLat",location.getLatitude());
        i.putExtra("currentLon",location.getLongitude());
        i.putExtra("positionCurr",pos);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("key", photos);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**then on the map activity i initialize them like this:**

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Marker marker;
        LatLng currentZone = null;
        LatLng plantLocation = null;
        LatLng photosLocation = null;
        positions = new ArrayList<>();


        allPhotos = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.allFotos);
        specificPhoto = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Photo);
        myPos = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myPos);
        Double currentLat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("currentLat", 0);
        Double currentLon = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("currentLon", 0);
        int currentPlantId = getIntent().getIntExtra("positionCurr",-1);

        allPhotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LatLng plantPos = new LatLng(positions.get(count).latitude,positions.get(count).longitude);
                count++;
                if(count == positions.size() - 1){
                    count = 0;
                }
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(plantPos, 35));
            }
        });

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        final ArrayList<Photo> photos = (ArrayList<Photo>) bundle.getSerializable("key");
        Log.d("photos",String.valueOf(photos.size()));

        if (currentLat != null && currentLon != null && currentLat != 0 && currentLon != 0) {
            currentZone = new LatLng(currentLat, currentLon);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentZone).title("Marker in Portugal"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentZone, 15));
            found = true;
        }

        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor;

        LatLng latLng;
        int positionSave = -1;
        int index = 0;


        for (final Photo p : photos) {
            if (p.getLat() != null && p.getLon() != null) // check for 0.0
            {
                if(p.getId() == currentPlantId ){
                    bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW);
                    plantLocation = new LatLng(p.getLat(),p.getLon());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(plantLocation, 35f));
                    found = true;
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(plantLocation)
                            .icon(bitmapDescriptor))
                            .setTag(p);
                }
                else{
                    bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN);
                    plantLocation = new LatLng(p.getLat(),p.getLon());
                    positions.add(plantLocation);
                    positionSave = index;
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(plantLocation)
                            .icon(bitmapDescriptor))
                            .setTag(p);
                }
                    photosLocation = new LatLng(p.getLat(), p.getLon());


            }
            index++;
        }
```

when i click on the marker the problem is displayed, sometimes i don't get the right id of the clicked photo, and i can see it with the yellow marker, the yellow marker represent the photo that i has selected in the previous activity, when i click on the yellow marker on the map the photo is diferent.

I already checked the passed id and it is correct, i tried to debug and everything seems fine when i set the tag, but when i receive the id is just wrong, i don't know what is really going on, is it because i can't pass a instance to the marker tag? or am i pointing to the same object? need some help with this.

**Here is the onClick for the marker:**

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

  @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Photo photo = new Photo();
            Boolean exist = false;
            List <Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();
               photo = (Photo)marker.getTag();
            Log.d("ph123",String.valueOf(photo.getId()));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            LayoutInflater inflater = MapsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            TextView countryTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.country);
            TextView cityTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.city);
            TextView streetTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.street);
            String street = null;
            String city = null;
            String country = null;
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder;
                geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

                address = geocoder.getFromLocation(photo.getLat(),photo.getLon(), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(address != null && address.size() > 0){
                street = address.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                city = getCity(address);

                if(street == null) {
                    street = address.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                }
                country = address.get(0).getCountryName();
            }


            if(street == null){
                street = "desconhecido";
            }

            if(country == null){
                country = "desconhecido";
            }

            countryTxt.setText(country);
            cityTxt.setText(city);
            streetTxt.setText(street);

            loadPhoto(photo.getPath(),image);
            dialog.setView(view);
            //searching marker id in locationDetailses and getting all the information of a particular marker


            // Create the AlertDialog
            //AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();


            // Add the button



        return false;
    }
});
```

}

**important part of the marker code:**

```
Photo photo = new Photo();
photo = (Photo)marker.getTag();
Log.d("ph123",String.valueOf(photo.getId())); // wrong id here
```

Any help would be appreciate,

Thanks!